# Deploy website with Git pull

Tags: shared-hosting, git

I have a website server with git to which I have ssh access.
I can pull to any folder above the public_html but the provider does not want to host git repositories so I cannot push to it.

The question is: what is the most convenient way of deploying and managing a website with git in this situation?

I do not think that an init in public_html is a good idea?

Comment: Buy your own server if you want freedom. It isn't called 'shared' hosting for nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You do this via git hooks.  You can configure your git hosting service (bitbucket or github) to call a url everytime you do a git push.  In essence you commit them push your changes to github/bitbucket and then those services do a request on a specific filename on your webserver.

In my scenario I have bitbucket always call http://www.mydomain.com/git-update.asp  and then git-update.asp actually runs a cmd prompt and does a git pull.

If you are on linux based server its a little bit easier via php. 
Check out this gist for more information:
https://gist.github.com/oodavid/1809044

If you are on a windows IIS server let me know and I will see if its cool for us to share our git deployment for windows code publicly.